# Updating Shipment lines's qty before confirming gives 'Error: Another process has updated the 'SOLine' record. Your changes will be lost."

Tags: c#, acumatica

A WMS provides the confirmation of the pick/pack and responds back with actual items to be shipped. Thus the request then updates the shipment lines QTY before confirming & processing

I tried playing around with cache and clearing graphs, etc. not avail

```cs
if (xmlDoc != null)
            {
                XmlNode root = xmlDoc.LastChild;

                if (root.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    logger += "Read XML File Elements. ";

                    //Header Data
                    string documentRef = "NO TRKNBR";
                    XmlNodeList DCH = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DCH");

                    string docNumber = DCH.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("Order_Id").InnerText;
                    documentRef = DCH.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("Shipment_Id").InnerText;
                    string docType = DCH.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("Status").InnerText;

                    if (docType == "Shipped")
                    {
                        //Details Data
                        XmlNodeList DCL = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DCL");

                        //Location Data
                        XmlNodeList DCHPTY = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DCHPTY");

                        SOOrderEntry soGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
                        SOShipmentEntry shipGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();

                        SOOrder soOrder = SelectFrom<SOOrder>.
                                          Where<SOOrder.orderNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.
                                          View.Select(this, docNumber);

                        SOOrderShipment soOrderShipment = SelectFrom<SOOrderShipment>.
                                                        Where<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.
                                                        View.Select(this, docNumber);

                        SOShipment soShipment = SelectFrom<SOShipment>.
                                                Where<SOShipment.shipmentNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.
                                                View.Select(this, soOrderShipment.ShipmentNbr);

                        shipGraph.Document.Current = soShipment;

                        //Get Shipment Extention
                        var soShipmentExt = soShipment.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>();
                        var soOrderExt = soOrder.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();

                        soShipmentExt.UsrDSVTrackingNumber = documentRef;
                        soOrderExt.UsrDSVActioned = 1;

                        soOrder = soGraph.Document.Update(soOrder);
                        soGraph.Actions.PressSave();
                        PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(soGraph.UID);
                        PXAutomation.CompleteAction(soGraph);

                        soShipment = shipGraph.Document.Update(soShipment);
                        shipGraph.Actions.PressSave();
                        PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(shipGraph.UID);
                        PXAutomation.CompleteAction(shipGraph);

                        shipGraph.Clear();
                        shipGraph.Document.Current = shipGraph.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(soShipment.ShipmentNbr);

                        InventoryItem inItem;

                        //Check if Shipment is in order
                        int lineNbr = 0;
                        string skuID = "";
                        decimal qtyShipped = 0M;
                        decimal qtyOrdered = 0M;
                        bool hasChanges = false;

                        foreach (XmlElement xmlElement in DCL)
                        {
                            foreach (SOShipLine soShipLine in shipGraph.Transactions.Select())
                            {
                                lineNbr = Convert.ToInt32(xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Line_Id").InnerText);
                                skuID = xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Sku_Id").InnerText;
                                qtyShipped = Convert.ToDecimal(xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Qty_Shipped").InnerText);
                                qtyOrdered = Convert.ToDecimal(xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Qty_Ordered").InnerText);

                                //Get IN Item Data
                                inItem = SelectFrom<InventoryItem>.
                                         Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.
                                         View.Select(this, skuID.Trim());

                                if (skuID.Trim() == inItem.InventoryCD.Trim() && qtyOrdered == soShipLine.OrigOrderQty)
                                {
                                    if (qtyShipped != soShipLine.ShippedQty)
                                    {
                                        shipGraph.Transactions.Current = soShipLine;

                                        soShipLine.ShippedQty = qtyShipped;

                                        shipGraph.Transactions.Update(soShipLine);

                                        shipGraph.CurrentDocument.UpdateCurrent();

                                        logger += "Item "+ skuID + " qty updated. ";
                                        hasChanges = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (hasChanges == true)
                        {
                            soShipment = shipGraph.Document.Update(soShipment);

                            shipGraph.Actions.PressSave();
                            PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(shipGraph.UID);
                            PXAutomation.CompleteAction(shipGraph);
                        }

                        shipGraph.Clear();
                        this.Caches.Clear();

                        shipGraph.Document.Current = shipGraph.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(soShipment.ShipmentNbr);

                        //Confirm Shipment
                        if (soShipment.Confirmed == false)
                        {                           
                            shipGraph.ConfirmShipment(soGraph, soShipment);
                            logger += "Shipment Confirmed. ";
                        }


//Check if Shipment is in order
int lineNbr = 0;
string skuID = "";
decimal qtyShipped = 0M;
decimal qtyOrdered = 0M;
bool hasChanges = false;

foreach (XmlElement xmlElement in DCL)
{
    foreach (SOShipLine soShipLine in shipGraph.Transactions.Select())
    {
        lineNbr = Convert.ToInt32(xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Line_Id").InnerText);
        skuID = xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Sku_Id").InnerText;
        qtyShipped = Convert.ToDecimal(xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Qty_Shipped").InnerText);
        qtyOrdered = Convert.ToDecimal(xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("Qty_Ordered").InnerText);

        //Get IN Item Data
        inItem = SelectFrom<InventoryItem>.
                 Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.
                 View.Select(this, skuID.Trim());

        if (skuID.Trim() == inItem.InventoryCD.Trim() && qtyOrdered == soShipLine.OrigOrderQty)
        {
            if (qtyShipped != soShipLine.ShippedQty)
            {
                shipGraph.Transactions.Current = soShipLine;

                soShipLine.ShippedQty = qtyShipped;

                shipGraph.Transactions.Update(soShipLine);

                shipGraph.CurrentDocument.UpdateCurrent();

                logger += "Item "+ skuID + " qty updated. ";
                hasChanges = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (hasChanges == true)
{
    soShipment = shipGraph.Document.Update(soShipment);

    shipGraph.Actions.PressSave();
    PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(shipGraph.UID);
    PXAutomation.CompleteAction(shipGraph);
}

#region Process DESADV0100

shipGraph.Clear();
this.Caches.Clear();

shipGraph.Document.Current = shipGraph.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(soShipment.ShipmentNbr);

//Confirm Shipment
if (soShipment.Confirmed == false)
{                           
    shipGraph.ConfirmShipment(soGraph, soShipment);
    logger += "Shipment Confirmed. ";
}
```

on the shipGraph Save & clear I expect the shipment to be confirmed and proceed with invoicing

Comment: In which event and for which graph extension that code is executed?

Comment: Hi Yuriy, it's on the Shipment Graph that is called in a process screen. Below the call from the start of the method: